# Interpreting residual plots from a regression problem using CNNs on image data

Tags: regression, residuals

My dataset consists of 799 images and each image is associated with a real number. I have split my dataset into 3 parts (80-10-10 split) randomly. I have trained my model using split1. The values follow a gaussian distribution.

I have trained an CNN model to output a real when an image is fed to it. These are my $R^2$ values and Residual plots for each of the dataset split.

**Split1:**

The split of the dataset that I trained my model on.

$R^2$ = $0.9857076788979228$

Residual plot:

[image]

**Split2:**

$R^2$ = 0.7396153728584336

Residual plot:

[image]

**Split3:**

$R^2$ = 0.7290908907070102

Residual plot:

[image]

I think that my model is biased, probably overfitting ( high $R^2$ value  on **Split1**). I don't understand why the $R^2$ values of **Split2** and **Split3** are nearly same and the Residual plots look similar.

What is the next step for me ? Should I reduce model complexity ?

EDIT: I have tried to reduce model complexity by reducing nonlinearities. The $R^2$ values decreases drastically for **Split2** and **Split3** by 0.3. And the residual plots are getting even more clustered. I'm stuck with this, I would greatly appreciate help at this point.

Comment: What do you mean by "reducing nonlinearities" in the context of CNNs (= convolutional neural networks)?

Comment: Reducing the number of layers in your model effectively reduces the model complexity and in between we use some kind of function of introduce non-linearity, so reducing number of layers reduces complexity and non-linearity.

Comment: What can you interpret after looking at the residuals ? I think the present model is not able to capture all of the deterministic part in the output variable. Am I correct ?